# Matrix naming on loop

Tags: matlab, octave

I'm writing a piece of code where I can define a number of matrices that will be generated and then a loop generates them. The piece where I'm struggling is on the "naming" of the matrices, since I want to name as follows: matrix1; matrix2; etc.

The code below is what I've got so far:

```
matrices_to_generate = 3;

for i=1:matrices_to_generate
  ['matrix' i] = rand(2,2);
end;
```

Comment: if the matrices are of the same size, why wont you assemble a 3d matrix? If their not, why wont you use a cell array?

Comment: What happens when you want to loop over all those matrices? Wouldn't it be easier to put all of these matrices in one array (or cell array) as @bla suggests and just use normal indexing?

Comment: It's handy to know how to name matrices, but the cell array approach actually suits better my needs, it makes my code way more dynamic, which is what I wanted, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `assignin`, you can write a variable to the workspace with a custom name.

```
for i=1:matrices_to_generate
  matrix = rand(2,2);
  assignin('base', strcat('matrix', num2str(i)), matrix);
end;
```